# I have an excel online file(business) and my company is hp. I want a way to download the excel file to my PC using python

Tags: python, excel, http, sharepoint, excel-online

**I tried using the below code but it is giving me 403 FORBIDDEN as the response**

```
import time
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

def share_point_login():
   print('called') 
   site=" url of the excel file"
   username = "username"
   password = "password"
   response = requests.get(site, auth=(username, password))         
   print(response.text)
   print(response.status_code)

share_point_login()
```

When I try downloading, I am getting a excel file with `403 FORBIDDEN` written in it.

the excel [URL File](https://hp.sharepoint.com/sites/EcosystemQualityTransformation/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FEcosystemQualityTransformation%2FShared%20Documents%2FIntegration%20Testing%20Workstream%2FSIV&FolderCTID=0x01200099FC13151BD2C64CB6EEE1608BF99BEB)

the same code is working for my friend in another laptop

Comment: Delete this post. It includes your user name and your password

Comment: And change your password immediately!

Comment: Please never post your email address and your password!

Comment: Thanks for help. I have changed the password and just mentioned password in my password in the code